# Java replace multiple substring in a string

Tags: java, regex

I have a Java String variable containing HTML in which I want to replace all the names of PNG images by another name.

Example input HTML

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="style.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img href="test1.png" />
    <img href="test2.png" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Typical output HTML should be

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="style.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img href="C:\foo\bar\test1.png" />
    <img href="C:\foo\bar\test2.png" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Currently I have this Java code that provides me the new name by loading the image as a ressource.
However I can't find the good regex to select all (and only) the images names (with extension but without quotes), can anyone help me on that ?

```
Pattern imagePattern = Pattern.compile(" TODO ");
Matcher imageMatcher = imagePattern.matcher(taskHTML);

while (imageMatcher.find())
{
    String oldName = imageMatcher.group(1);
    String newName = "" + getClass().getResource("/images/" + imageMatcher.group(1));

    taskHTML.replace(oldName, newName);
}
```

The matcher should list the following elements:

```
[test1.png, test2.png]
```

Comment: I suggest better use HTML parser for this .

Comment: @AchintyaJha Could you detail please ? Do you have any link that provides more details about an HTML parser ?

Comment: You can google and find  many ( http://jsoup.org/)

Comment: [just google it](https://www.google.de/?gws_rd=ssl#q=java+html+parser)

Comment: HTML parser seems a bit overkill for my needs, plus it adds a dependency in my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the following regular expression:

```
Pattern.compile("\\\"(.+\\.png)\\\"");
```

And accessing the match between the quotes by getting the second element of each match (the first is the string with the quotes):

```
matcher.group(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Like others have mentioned, I suggest you use an HTML parser like [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/).

**Usage:**

```
import org.jsoup.nodes.*;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;

public class Parse {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String webPage = "<img href=\"test1.png\" /><img href=\"test2.png\" />"; //your HTML

        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(webPage);

        Elements imgLinks = doc.select("img[href]"); //grabs all imgLinks

        //for every <img> link
        for(Element link : imgLinks){           
            String imageName = link.attr("href"); //grab current href (your image name)
        link.attr("href", "C:\\foo\\bar\\" + imageName); //replace current href with the dir + imageName

        }
        System.out.println(doc.html()); //print modified HTML
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <img href="C:\foo\bar\test1.png"> 
        <img href="C:\foo\bar\test2.png">
    </body>
</html>
```

If you have a local HTML file that you want to parse, you will want to replace the `doc` above with this:

```
File in = new File(input);
Document doc = JSoup.parse(in, null);
```

Or if you want to directly connect to a page you can replace it with this:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://stackoverflow.com/").get();
```

**Note:** You will need to add JSoup to your buildpath

Comment: Useful but I ended up using a regexp (see my answer).

Comment: @Spotted glad you found a solution! Just a little pointer, it's not advised to use regex to parse html. For reasons read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751105/why-its-not-possible-to-use-regex-to-parse-html-xml-a-formal-explanation-in-la). Anyway, don't forget to accept an answer to close the question :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
str = str.replaceAll("href=\"(.*?)\"", "href=\"" + dir.replace("\\", "\\\\") + "$1\"");
```

Answer (score 0):

Whether you need to modify HTML content consider using XSLT instead of REGEXP.